# Substance designer nodes in blender shader?

Tags: materials

is it possible to use substance designer " nodes " in blender shader ?
I know you can use ready-made materials.
but I want to know if it is possible to mix the substance designer nodes with the blender nodes.

it works ?

thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, but no.  Blender has no idea how to interpret substance designer's internal data structures.

Comment: is it possible to bevel the mesh with substance designer? like? do you have a tutorial?
thanks

Comment: Alas, I don't.  Sorry.

Comment: and create curvature with substance designer, do you have a tutorial?

Comment: is the Republished sbsar working?
Do you have any settings for it to work?